# Windows Boot Manager appears only randomly

Tags: windows, boot, multi-boot, boot-manager

I had Windows 10 on my laptop and I've installed Windows 7 on different partition.
 At the beginning everything was fine, but after 3 weeks Windows Boot Loader started to not showing up, randomly. 
Sometimes it shows up, but most of the time it doesn't and Windows 10 is loaded immediately.
Even on BIOS "boot from" options I can select to boot from "Windows Boot Manager" but then also selection screen doesn't appear and Win10 is loaded instantly.

In msconfig on both Win10 and Win7 there are 2 entries and Win7 is set as default, the counter is set to 30 sec.

I can't see any pattern, except I found out one way to make Windows Boot Loader appear in 100% of times:
when I force shutdown when Win10 is loading - the next time I turn on the computer Windows Boot Manager will always show up . But it's not a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just a guess, but Windows 10 actually does not really shut down; instead it uses a feature called Fast Boot, using hybernation. This is the reason, why Windows 10 is able to start up really quick, but it often causes trouble in multi-boot environments.

To disable it completely (boot time increases just a little bit by doing this):

1. Open the start menu by clicking the Windows logo and type "Power and sleep"
2. Scroll down and click on "Additional Power Settings"
3. On the left side, click on "Choose what the power button does"
4. Uncheck the box "Enable Fast Boot" (To change settings here, you might have to login with admin privileges)

Please let me know if this solved your problem.

Comment: I have power button settings set to "sleep", however it's not the case - I never use power button to turn off computer, I always shut down using Menu start -> Shutdown. It always waits for all aplications to close, so it doesn't save any session.

Comment: It is a missleading naming convention of Microsoft - the settings in "Choose what the power button does" affect even "Virtual Powerbuttons" or shutdown behaviour in general. So - it's worth trying it since you can't really break stuff here.

Comment: You was right, after many tests I comfirmed it was that issue! Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

maybe boot settings got disturbed due to something. Run free EasyBCD and see what entries are there, which is default, how much time is allotted, etc. and then save it,

Then, **the following is very powerful and if anything is done differently, it can mess up and your system will not boot, so please do it very very carefully** -

1. in the left pane of buttons, click on the "BCD/ backup repair".
2. on that pane, tick on the second entry, "recreate/ repair boot files".
3. click "perform action" button below that once.
4. close EasyBCD.

it will re-write all boot records and then it should run as you saw in EasyBCD.

If it doesn't work that way, then problem is surely somewhere else.

Thanks.